# How to tell if the MBA (Mavericks) is connected to the 2.4 or 5 ghz network?

Tags: macos, wifi

I've been having issues connecting to wifi access points, and I am wondering if the band is messing things up.  How do I tell what band a wifi connection is using on the laptop if I don't have access to the router settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Option + Wifi Menu

Hold the [Option key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key) down and select your WiFi icon in the menu bar ( ⌥ + [image] ).

Additional information in the menu includes “Channel:” and (5 GHz) or (2.4 GHz) for the current radio settings.

As seen in Yosemite:

[image]

## Wireless Diagnostics.app

You can get even more information from System Information. But I usually open the [Wireless Diagnostics app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202663) (in Applications > Utilities folder). Choose `Window` > `Info` to get more detailed WiFi networking or scan for better channels, check for interference, etc.

[image]

Comment: Nice, well hidden, but Cmd-2 opens it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/), which specifies the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

About This Mac > More Info > System Report > Network > WiFi

> [image: PICTURE]